# How to create a class that can analyze all 10 txt files in a file?

Tags: python, class, nlp, zip

I have created a class that analyzes the text file with functions 'average_word_length' and 'average_sentence_length'. The text are ten stories stored in the folder 'stories'. I would like to create a code that reads all 10 files in the 'stories' folder and returns all the results at once. However I am seemingly able to analyze only one text file in the folder.

My entire code looks like that:

```
from os.path import splitext
from os.path import basename
from glob import glob
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
import nltk as nlp 
import re 

def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, encoding='utf8') as infile:
        contents = infile.read()
    return contents

def remove_ext(filename):
    root, ext = splitext(filename)
    return root

def remove_dir(filepath):
    return basename(filepath)

def remove_dir_ext(filepath):
    no_ext = remove_ext(filepath)
    base = remove_dir(no_ext)
    return base

def get_story(filepath):
    return int(remove_dir_ext(filepath))
```

```
# importing required modules
import zipfile
from zipfile import ZipFile
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')

# specifying the zip file name
file_name = "stories_n10.zip.2"

# opening the zip file in READ mode
with ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zip:
    # printing all the contents of the zip file
    zip.printdir()

    # extracting all the files
    zip.extractall()
```

```
corpus = []
filenames = glob('story1.txt')
filenames = sorted(filenames, key=get_story)
for filename in filenames:
    text = read_file(filename)
```

```
#number of letters
number_od_letters=sum(len(x) for x in text.split())

#Counting number of words
s = text
len(s.split())
number_of_words=len(text.split())

#Counting number of sentences
sentences = text

number_of_sentences = sent_tokenize(sentences)

no_of_sentences=len(number_of_sentences)
```

```
#average_sentence_length=number of words/ number of sentences

average_sentence_length= number_of_words/no_of_sentences

# average_word_length = total number of letters/ total number of words

average_word_length= number_od_letters/number_of_words
```

```
class TextAnalysis:
    def __init__(self, average_word_length, average_sentence_length):
        self.average_word_length = average_word_length
        self.average_sentence_length = average_sentence_length
print(average_word_length, average_sentence_length)
```

And the output are two numbers for example.

3, 21

Now I would like to create the class that takes ALL the files in the folder at once and returns all 20 results from all files of the folder. For example this:

3, 21

2, 23

5, 17

5, 43

1, 34

3, 67

8, 71

3, 75

1, 37

4, 61

But then each time I try to get the entire folder I am getting an error, so I can only get one file (the sotry) at once.
Anyone knows how to compute imput in multiple files at once? I don't want to copy paste my code all ten times, but then nothing else seems to work.

I tried multiple alteration of using 'glob' file, but nothing seemed to work: when I add the name of the entire folder I receive the error

invalid literal for int() with base 10

Comment: What is the error message you are getting, for which code part of your code?

Comment: is there unnecessary quotes `filenames = glob('TEXT(1)'.txt')`?

Comment: TypeError: glob() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: what file names in zip maybe you need to do this `filenames = glob('text*.txt')`?

Comment: what structure of folders inside of your zip?

Comment: this line`zip.extractall()` extracts all files and `filenames = glob('text*.txt')` gives list of extracted files `['text 1.txt', 'text 2.txt']`

Comment: you can walk through list of files  `['text 1.txt', 'text 2.txt']` and calculate words and sentences for each

Comment: please show what list you got after `filenames = glob('TEXT(1)'.txt')`

Comment: this class `TextAnalysis` does not calculate, it accepts results of calculation instead of filename to analyse

Comment: @Ronin I got an error 'EOL while scanning string literal'

Comment: can you give details code files to reproduce problem and help you?

Comment: When I try to add the entire folder TEXT(1) I get an error ''invalid literal for int() with base 10:''

Comment: @Ronin I updated my question with the entire code I wrote so far

Comment: `filenames = glob('story1.txt')` it not wildcard search instead you search for exact file thats why you got only one result.